# In order to increase variance, can I get my items classified twice by each participant?

Tags: variance, scales

I have a set of items (10 per domain: 5 domains in total) that participants need to classify according to a 5-way forced choice scale and that I want to use to generate accuracy scores for participants. Because of their nature, I cannot easily produce more of these items (they are performance/ability tasks), and I have concerns about the variance being large enough to use in individual differences analyses (i.e. correlation, SEM). Is it acceptable to give each of the items twice to participants, so as to boost the variance of the scale, or does this violate some assumption of the subsequent analyses I am hoping to do?

I hope that's clear. 
Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: So each item has one correct answer and 4 incorrect ones? You use the words scale and accuracy which seem incompatible.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. Yes, each item has 1 correct and 4 incorrect answers. My measure for each item is whether it was classified correctly or incorrectly by the participant. Because I aim to look at individual differences I am worried about having too little variance with only ten occurrences of each domain.

Comment: If you ask participants to do a task twice, you'll want to treat the data as repeated measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the number of samples never increases, or decreases, variance. It only makes the estimate of variance more accurate. Moreover, in this case, asking the same question repeatedly will likely result in just more of the same answers. Imagine what would happen to variability if I had two questions and I asked each 10 times?

You have binomial data, which has an analytic solution for variance based soley on proportion correct (p) (`p*(1-p)`). Therefore, increasing the sampling, as much as it increases the accuracy of the estimate of p, will increase the accuracy of the variance estimate.

Looking at it another way variance across subjects (SE of one subject) will actually go down if you increase the number of questions. So, if you wanted that higher then you're not helping yourself adding questions (but you don't want that higher).

You probably shouldn't be doing any correlations, you'll be doing something else with binomial outcomes, probably chi-square.